# MVC Update Master-Child Records

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to update a Master-Child recordset in MVC.

My Customer has a ContactPerson, who has an Address.
In my EditView only a few properties are Displayed to the user to Edit.
On posting, only the Displayed data is put in my Objects. So i Need to get the Objects from the Database by their Id's and then map the edited data.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer, ContactPerson contactPerson, Address address)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            ContactPerson cp = db.ContactPersons.Where(c => c.Id == contactPerson.Id).Single();
            Address adr = db.Adresses.Where(a => a.id == address.id).Single();
            customer.ContactPerson = cp;
            cp.Addresses.Add(adr);
            db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

            cp.Surname = contactPerson.Surname;
            cp.LastName = contactPerson.LastName;
            cp.Email = contactPerson.Email;
            cp.Homepage = contactPerson.Homepage;
            ........
            db.Entry(cp).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

Is this really the way to do this, or am i missing some beautifull trick of the MVC Framework ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddOrUpdate`.

I don't know if this qualifies as a "trick", but you can do this (some may argue this way is not a best practice, but **it does work**). 
Note the `using` statements I've used to allow you to use the `AddOrUpdate`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer, ContactPerson contactPerson, Address address)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        ContactPerson cp = db.ContactPersons.Where(c => c.Id == contactPerson.Id).Single();
        Address adr = db.Adresses.Where(a => a.id == address.id).Single();
        customer.ContactPerson = cp; // There's a chance another db.SaveChanges() call should be made after this line.
        cp.Addresses.Add(adr);            
        db.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id, cp); // The lambda expression is for the key                  
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

**Another note:**

If what you want is to avoid reassigning the non-displayed fields, I believe that the `AddOrUpdate` would actually update only those fields where you put values into. So leave the non displayed empty and test if that works.

Comment: The saving is not what concerns me, I dont actually want to retrieve (again) the data to "reassign" the values of the non-displayed fields...

Comment: I believe that the `AddOrUpdate` would actually update only those fields where you put values into. So leave the non displayed empty and test if that works. I've updated my answer to refer to this issue. Hope that helps...